# Как правильно переопределить класс QSqlTableModel?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Я нашел в интернете переопределенный класс
tablemodel.h:

```
class TableModel : public QSqlTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit TableModel(QObject *parent = 0);
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &idx, int role) const;

};
```

tablemodel.cpp

```
#include "tablemodel.h"
#include <QColor>

TableModel::TableModel(QObject *parent) : QSqlTableModel(parent)
{

}

QVariant TableModel::data(const QModelIndex &idx, int role) const
{
    if(role == Qt::BackgroundColorRole){
        if(QSqlTableModel::data(this->index(idx.row(), 0)).toInt() == 6){
            return QColor(Qt::red);
        }
    } else if(role == Qt::DisplayRole){
        return QSqlTableModel::data(idx);
    }
    return QVariant();
}
```

И все бы хорошо, но в таблице с моделью этого класса при двойном нажатии исчезают данные ячейки, не копируются, ведет себя странно. Как правильно его переопределить его, чтобы работало как с QSqlTableModel?

Comment: Попробуйте изменить условие на: `} else if (role == Qt::DisplayRole || role == Qt::EditRole) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас отсутствует обработка `Qt::EditRole`. Возможно причина в этом

Comment: Да стопудов в этом и причина :) Ведь двойной клик вызывает редактирование, а данные для этого как раз из Qt::EditRole и получает представление.

Comment: Добвалю, что если хотите использовать `Qt::EditRole`, то нужно также переопределить метод `QAbstractItemModel::flags`.

Comment: QAbstractItemModel::flags не переопределял, но вроде и так работает

Comment: @MadokaMagica, переопределив `flags`, вы сможете указывать, какие данные можно редактировать, а какие нельзя.